# Network goerli doesn’t exist message while deploying

Tags: node.js, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, hardhat

I am trying to deploy my `deploy.js` file, but when I use the script 'deploy' I get a messages about “**Network goerli doesn’t exist**”.

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-waffle")

module.exports = {
    solidity: {
        compilers: [{ version: "0.8.8" }, { version: "0.6.6" }]
    },
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0 //here this will by default take the first account as deployer
        }
    },
    network: {
        goerli: {
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 5,
            blockConfirmation: 6
        }
    }
}
```

And this is  my configuration for **APIs** and environment:

```
// Add API key and private key
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()
require("hardhat-deploy")

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
/** @type   import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig    */
const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = “PRIVATE_KEY”; const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = “API_KEY”;
```

Is there any way to help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried finally the configuration below? @Omphile James

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add API Key and Private Keys

require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()
require("hardhat-deploy")

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
/** @type   import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig    */
```

const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = “PRIVATE_KEY”;
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = “API_KEY”;

Comment: I have edited your main question and I've added that information too, you can delete this answer if you approve the edition above @Omphile ;)

Comment: It's unclear whether you're trying to provide more code along with your question or if you've found a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in `hardhat.config.js`. it should be `networks` not "network"

```
networks: {
  goerli: {
    url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
    accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
    chainId: 5,
    blockConfirmation: 6
  }
}
```